# Script loads only first function for 2 different inputs instead of loading them sepparately

Tags: jquery

This is 2 different functions for 2 inputs - inputStringVga and inputStringCpu, however it always loads only the first function, even then 2 inputs have different ID (inputStringVga and inputStringCpu) Why it's so? And how to make them load their function instead of loading only first function query ?

```
function lookup(inputStringVga) {
    if(inputStringVga.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
    } else {
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryStringVga: ""+inputStringVga+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
            $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
        });
    }
}
function lookup(inputStringCpu) {
    if(inputStringCpu.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
    } else {
        $.post("rpc.php", {queryStringCpu: ""+inputStringCpu+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
            $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
        });
    }
}
```

rpc.php file

```
$querystring = JRequest::getVar('queryStringCpu');
    if(isset($querystring)) {
if(strlen($querystring) >0) {

    $query = "SELECT cpuname FROM #__cpu WHERE cpuname LIKE '%" . $querystring . "%' ORDER BY cpuname LIMIT 50";
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $db->query( $query ) or die('Blogai');
    $qq = $db->loadObjectList();

    foreach ($qq as $aa) {
    echo '<div class="aa">'.$aa->cpuname.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
$querystring2 = JRequest::getVar('queryStringVga');

    if(isset($querystring2)) {
if(strlen($querystring2) >0) {

    $query2 = "SELECT vganame FROM #__cpu WHERE vganame LIKE '%" . $querystring2 . "%' ORDER BY vganame LIMIT 50";
    $db->setQuery( $query2 );
    $db->query( $query2 ) or die('Blogai');
    $qq2 = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($qq2 as $aa2) {
    echo '<div class="aa1">'.$aa2->vganame.'</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from what I think you're trying to do, you'll want something like this:

```
<input name="'.$this->name.'" type="text" size="50" value="'.$this->value.'" id="inputStringVga" onkeyup="lookup(this.value, this.id);" /></input> <div id="suggestions"></div>
```

and your JS:

```
function lookup(val, id) {
    if(val.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
    } else {
        aa = {};
        aa[id] = ""+val+"";
        $.post("rpc.php", aa, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
            $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
            $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
        });
    }
}
```

Might need to mess about with how that associative array is being formed, but none-the-less..

Comment: I updated the question, please look at rpc file, i hope it will be more clear. And everything worked well only with 1 function, so i'm not sure if there's a need to change scheme of function.

Comment: It worked with one function because you only wanted to do one thing. Now you want to do two things, so you either need to have two (_differently named_) functions, or you need to change your function. The function I wrote above sends either `queryStringVga` or `queryStringCpu` based on the ID of the input.

Comment: I tried change name of functions, but didn't worked. i will try your js,I hope it helps

Comment: note, I'm not sure if I'm forming the hash correctly, I don't do a lot of JS. I just updated it with something that could work if my previous code didn't. You couldn't just change the name of the function without changing how you're calling it, that's why that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

They both are the **same functions**. So one function will be **overwritten** by the `signature of current function`. As function definitions are first read before any of the code is read.

Both have the same signature  `function lookup()`  .. The number of arguments do not come into question.

Comment: I changed the name of second function, but effect remain the same.

Comment: What exactly is inputStringVga ??

Comment: It's id of input `<input name="'.$this->name.'" type="text" size="50" value="'.$this->value.'" id="inputStringVga" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" /></input>
 <div id="suggestions"></div>'`

Comment: If you want to pass the ID .. You seem to be passing the value to the data of post instead of ID